# Getting an indentation error after autoreload statement in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

I encounter an error while running the following code in PyCharm.

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import funcs as f

for i in range(1):
    df = f.read_data()
```

The error I get is:

> ```
>   File "<ipython-input-16-7841cd68b0d1>", line 7
>     df = f.read_data()
>      ^
> IndentationError: expected an indented block
> ```

The code throws the error when I select the code and press `CTRL + Enter`. However, the code works fine when I run the magic statements and the rest of the code separately, or when I run the code by copy-pasting it into the iPython console.

In the gif below, you can see that when pressing `CTRL + Enter`, the indentation seems to disappear from the code (I have tried both `tab` and spaces).

This confuses me, because the code runs in the same console independently of which method I use to run it. I am very curious to know what causes the difference. Is the code interpreted differently? Am I using the magic statements incorrectly?

---

[image]

---

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Is line 7 indented with 4 spaces or with tabs? Could the interpreter somehow expect a different number of spaces as indentation? What changes if you do 2, 4, 6 or 8 spaces?

Comment: @Thijs, I tried both 2,4,6 and 8 spaces and 1 or 2 tabs, but the issue remains.

Comment: I don't know if it make sense but does `%load_ext autoreload` and  `%autoreload 2` have any role?

Comment: @Rahul [Yes](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html). This snippet is part of a larger chunk of code. If there are other simple ways to achieve the same functionality as the `autoreload` statements, I'd be happy to hear them (I'd prefer not to use `reload()` for each function). But even then, I am still curious why the code above does not work.